# get selected month value in dropdown list if using an array

Tags: php, arrays, date, select

I am trying to get the selected value in the drop down; but the items inside it are in an array. How can I get the value of the selected option?

For now, I have these lines of code:

```
<?php
// lowest year wanted
$cutoff = 2013;

// current year
$now = date('Y');

// build months menu
echo '<select name="month">' . PHP_EOL;
for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {
    echo '  <option value="' . $m . '">' . date('M', mktime(0,0,0,$m)) . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</select>' . PHP_EOL;

// build days menu
echo '<select name="day">' . PHP_EOL;
for ($d=1; $d<=31; $d++) {
    echo '  <option value="' . $d . '">' . $d . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</select>' . PHP_EOL;

// build years menu
echo '<select name="year">' . PHP_EOL;
for ($y=$now; $y>=$cutoff; $y--) {
    echo '  <option value="' . $y . '">' . $y . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</select>' . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Let's say, I picked July for the month. How can I tell the browser that I have chosen July. Any idea?

Comment: you want to get value of selected one using javascirpt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
echo '<select name="month">' . PHP_EOL;
for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {
    if($sel_mnth == $m)
        echo '  <option value="' . $m . '" selected="selected">' . date('M', mktime(0,0,0,$m)) . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
    else   
        echo '  <option value="' . $m . '">' . date('M', mktime(0,0,0,$m)) . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</select>' . PHP_EOL;
```

or directly

```
for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {                   
        echo '  <option value="' . $m . '" if($sel_mnth == $m) echo "selected=\'selected\'";>' . date('M', mktime(0,0,0,$m)) . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for a quick response. Just to clarify, I want to display the value of the Month that was selected. Is that how your code works? For example, I set month to December, how can I tell the code that the selected value is December? Does that make any sense? I'm sorry for this.

Comment: It will check with the month count,for example For december it will be 12

Comment: I see. Well then, I'll give it a go and see how it works. If not I'll go back to you, if yes I'll give you a check mark. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Put your `select` within a `form` tag  and after submit the form use
`$_POST['month']` or `$_POST['year']` for getting month and year user selected value.

like this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$year=$_POST['year']; //user selected year value is here
...
}

<form method="POST" action="">
... //here is your select tag codes
...
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
    <option value="">--Select Month--</option>
    <?php for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++)
    {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
        <?php
    } ?>

</select>
```

Comment: please explain or use explanatory comments!